# Query contains too many nested clauses; maxClauseCount is set to 1024

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have been getting this error when running an elastic query against and index for a search. i was not getting this error in my earlier version of elastic, but after migrating to 8.3 i am getting this error. i see that in earlier versions of elastic we were able to set the max clause count using the field "indices.query.bool.max_clause_count" in the elaaticsearch.yml file but since 8.0 this has been deprecated and will have no impact even if the property is set.
According to the elastic documentation i see that now the max clause count is dynamically calculated based on the heap size of the JVM and few other parameters as mentioned in this documentation.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html

I am looking to see if we can any we have to capability of figuring out what heap size of JVM would give me the desired clause count?   or what cluster specifications should i use for me to get the desired clause count??

This is the sample query i have been using.

```
{
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "this is search and test"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "hideFromSearch": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "this is search and test",
                                "type": "phrase"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": "this is search and test",
                                "operator": "and"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

if the search keyword is anything more than 1 word.. then the search is giving the error.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need 1024 clauses for your query, may be try to optimize your search/ filter criteria instead of piling up more resources to avoid such scenarios. ES recommends max upto 64G of memory which means 32G of heap size. Although its enough for all your cases, but recommendation would still be search optimization.